# Update the DOM without refreshing the page in React.js

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

I am fetching the data from the API (fake REST API built with json-server) in my react app. I want the app to be updated automatically without refreshing manually as any changes occur in the API. How do I do this? the code is below:

```
import './App.css'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function App() {
const [post, setPost]=useState([])
const url="http://localhost:3000/users"

useEffect(()=>{
axios
.get(url)
.then(res=>{
   setPost(res.data)
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})

},[])

const showUsers=
post.map(item=>{
return(
<div className="card" key={item.id}>
<h2>Name: {item.name}</h2>
<h3>Username: {item.username}</h3>
<p>Email:{item.email}</p>
</div>
        
)
})}

return (
<div className="container">
{showUsers}
</div>
   )
}
```

**NOTE** I attempted to put `post` state variable, in the dependency array of `useEffect` hook, and it worked as I wanted but it started to send infinite `get requests` to the server. Something like that

```
useEffect(()=>{
axios
.get(url)
.then(res=>{
   setPost(res.data)
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})

},[post])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's talk about why putting `post` in the `useEffect` dependency causes infinite requests. As stated:

> You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders.

but the problem is that every time you call the effect, you actually change `post` by calling `setPost`. this causes a re-render. while react is doing the re-render it checks whether it should run the effect again or not. since the variable `post` in the `useEffect` has changed, react decides to run the effect again. this causes the infinite loop.

---

Back to your main question. If I understood correctly you want to sync your application's state with the server's state regarding `posts`. You can achieve that by [polling or websockets](https://ably.com/blog/websockets-vs-long-polling.). in polling the client send a request to the server every few seconds to check if there has been any chaneges in the state. [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) make it possible to have a two-way connection between the server and client. the two-way connection makes it possible for the server to send information to the client at any time.

below is a **very simple** polling solution to your problem. I strongly encourage you to read more about the concept.

```js
// ommited code
  const [post, setPost]=useState([])
  const url="http://localhost:3000/users"
  const WAIT_TIME = 5000;

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      axios
     .get(url)
     .then(res=>{
       setPost(res.data);
     })
     .catch(err=>{
       console.log(err);
     })
    }, WAIT_TIME);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [post]); 
// omitted code
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you Arsalan, it worked as expected. I am gonna accept your answer. But tell me one thing, is it good to send **get ** request to server after every **5 seconds**? Does the server not become overwhelmed?

Comment: it does put a lot of pressure on the server. I recommend using Websocket.

Answer (score 0):

By default useEffect run on each update.

If you give `,[post])`

It tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values (post) haven’t changed between re-renders.

If you want fetch only at mount use an `,[])`

The react doc explain this very well:
[Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: But when I keep the **useEffect** dependency array blank, It does not send the infinite requests (that is good) but I am to reload the document to see the changes in the data. That is what I don't want. I want the content to be updated instantly without reloading the web.